Help with designing and structuring a modern Confederate States military?
Basically in my world, the South won the Civil War and from 1865 onwards, the United States and Confederate States are bitter rivals and absolutely detest one another (and per the Grant Doctrine, the U.S. refuses to accept, acknowledge, or recognize Confederate independence even to this day, seeing the country as a gang of rogue breakaway states in a state of continuous rebellion against the federal government). From 1963-1967, the two nations fought another war (Texas War), officially ending in an armistice but everyone knew it was a major de facto U.S. victory since the U.S. managed to retake chunks of Confederate territory (this would also help propel the U.S. to become the second global superpower behind China). To this day (2024), the two nations are bitter enemies and it’s inevitable that the two would clash again.
About the Confederate military, I have a couple minor questions about it:
My main question is, if the CSA were to somehow exist in the 21st Century as an impoverished, corrupt totalitarian dictatorship with an equally corrupt and poor military, what would the Confederate military actually be like?
Right now I’m having the majority of the Confederate military be in an abysmal and appalling state. It’s poorly trained and equipped, morale is low, corruption is rife throughout the ranks, etc. Some of the troops can’t even have 3 proper meals a day. The only saving grace the military has are its sheer numbers, surprisingly relatively fresh combat experience against U.S.-backed rebels and in another war with the Americans, they’ll have home court advantage. The CS Government also puts a ton of money and resources into its SOF elements, although this is more for propaganda and COIN purposes. But is this at all realistic for the CSA? Also:

Would it make sense for the military to be classist in nature? So far in the CS military, I’m having the rank structure be incredibly classist, with officers being given a much higher standard of living, better pay, better/newer equipment, and priority access to things like healthcare. I'm not talking about how it is like in modern (Western) militaries where there's still a level of meritocracy, I mean like "between this Sgt/E-5 with a blown off leg and a 2nd Lt/O-2 with a sprained ankle, we're gonna treat the Lt first".

Would the military be racially integrated or segregated? I feel like when talking about the Confederacy, you can’t ignore race and I’m still having trouble tackling this particular issue since I an see arguments made for both.

Does it make sense for the CS Navy to have an amphibious assault ship? So far I’m having the CS Navy’s flagship and most prized possession be the French-built Mistral-class amphibious assault ship CSS Jefferson Davis. It’s used for power projection throughout the CSA’s Caribbean holdings and is a point of pride for the Confederate States.


What would the CS military’s primary service rifle be? I’m stuck between either the G3 or FN FAL but I’ve also thought about having them create an entirely new rifle.

If the Confederacy is so decrepit and its armed forces are so weak, what's stopping the United States from simply marching in? Most of the territory of the Confederacy is an open plain, simply indefensible against a modern army with aircraft and tanks. Home advantage cannot help all that much when your territory is ideal tank land and the enemy is overwhelmingly better trained and better equipped. I believe you would do better to make the CSA a rich developed country if you want to have it still exist.

Too many questions in one post, and some of them are opinion based.

VTC - There are too many really big events between the US Civil War and your time period. Would the US enter WW1? Maybe, Maybe not. If they don't create a Blue Water navy (which they really did around WW1) would Japan bomb Pearl Harbour? Maybe, maybe not. Manhattan Project? Start of the Cold War? You could write an entire book on the Premise - and as such, it is unanswerable.

@TheDemonLord While I agree that it's hard to say with any degree of certainty, you can extrapolate to an extent from the CSA as it existed in real life.

@InHocSigno - Saw your answer - but America's entry into WW1 - which IMO is causal for so many things that happened in the 20th century is uncertain with a divided US. In fact, I would go so far as to say it's rather unlikely. That changes so many things that you could write a book on it.

@TheDemonLord Good point.

For your Navy, the Anaconda Plan must have failed or there would be no CSA. So how did they plan to counter that 50 years ago, 100 years ago? Say they have a couple of obsolete coastal defense battleships, designed 100 years ago, built 80 years ago, last modernized 30 years ago, and still armed with 12" guns (good for coastal bombardment only, these days). And reasonably quiet coastal diesel subs, designed 50 years ago, built 30 years ago, and possibly still useful as 'mobile minefields.' Those are the successors of 75-year-old fleet submarines, which were pretty good for their time ...

This whole timeline seems super unrealistic to me.  First off, the Economies of the North and South were highly dependant on one another up to and after the civil war.   Northern Industry was powered by Southern raw materials.  One way or another, as soon as the Civil War was over, economists on both sides would want to scramble to re-establish a peaceful system of trade; so, odds are that resentment between the North and South would have healed even faster if the South won because it would eliminate the Reconstruction Era abuse of one side being treated as a conquered territory.

As a general rule, necessity breeds stronger alliances than resentment of generations past can sustain. Secondly, China's rise to power was a direct consequence of American Globalism, but the US has no reason to outsource work to China's cheap labor market if thier closest neighbor to the South still has a thriving slave economy.  So, the Southern Slavers would have gotten the industrial economic stimulus from America's tech boom, not China.  Lastly, "totalitarian dictatorship" goes against the whole premise of Southern culture of and the founding principles of the Confederacy.

While the South was slave driven economy, the South did not rebel to protect slavery.  Not enough freemen had a vested interest in slaves to care about that.  They rebelled because the House, Senate, and Presidency all became majority Northern Republican run which, in a winner take all political system, effectively left Southern freemen unrepresented in the Federal Government.  This allowed the North to pass any laws they wanted against the Southern Democrats (including but not limited to abolition).  The real point of contention was the Supremacy of Federal Law.

From the very beginnings of the US, the North had a history of wanting to create a strong central authority Federalism whereas the South wanted power spread out Confederacy.  Because the South rebelled to make the supremacy of law a State Level power, this would make it virtually impossible for any one person or group of people to execute a totalitarian regime.

If anything, the North would be more likely to fall under totalitarianism if the South and Southern Confederate Idealism had not been forced back into Congress to maintain the balance between these ideologies. So, individual States might evolve thier own very draconian legal systems with limited federal oversight to stop them, but the Confederate government itself did not have the authority over people's day-to-day lives to be totalitarian.

@Nosajimiki Do you mean capital-F "Federalism" (which is really nationalism; Hamilton et al. pulled a Bolsheviks vs. Mensheviks), or lowercase "f" federalism?

@InHocSigno Federalism and Nationalism are not quite the same. Federalism defines the relationship of your central government as being superior to the state governments that it oversees. Nationalism defines your central government as being superior to external governments that are not under its jurisdiction... that said, Nationalists tend to also be Federalists because of the shared ideology in the superiority of their central government.


But is this at all realistic for the CSA?

First off, as TheDemonLord has pointed out in the question comments, it's difficult or impossible to say anything with a good degree of accuracy. The closest we can do is extrapolate from the CSA as it existed in real life, assuming that the rest of history goes (more or less) the same.
Relative to each of your sub-questions:
Classism in the military
While it's your story (and therefore you have freedom to modify things as you see fit), the IRL Confederate military wasn't anywhere as near as classist as you posit, nor do I see it becoming that way if the CSA survived the Civil War. It did have a "gentleman officer" stereotype, but that was true of every Western military at the time.
Dictatorship
Similarly, the CSA's central government (if you can call it that) wasn't very powerful; as per its name, the Confederacy was staunchly federalist (i.e., states as semi-countries that have decided to work together for the common good). While nowhere near as bad as the Articles of Confederation-era United States (the CSA's constitution was mostly copy-pasted from the US one, which was designed specifically to solve the Articles' issues), there was still a lot of interstate rivalry and general dysfunction going on (cf. NATO's issues with problem members such as Türkiye gumming up the works for personal gain).
That said, there is still a possibility that it could have become a dictatorship; as a popular hero that the people respected, General Lee held a great deal of power, and it's not inconceivable that he could have officially or unofficially taken over the CS government if it survived (although, being a firm federalist, whether he would or not is another question. If you're fixed on a nationalized, authoritarian CSA, you could swing it as him pulling a Dumbledore and acting for the "Greater Good™".)
Another question would be whether Lee would last very long as a peacetime dictator. Remember, the CSA was founded in large part as a response to the North's attempts to centralize power (nationalism) and "creatively interpret" the legal system to accomplish its policy goals (i.e., end slavery)*. A dictator would fly in the face of that. Then again, wars tend to loosen up governments, so who knows what would actually happen?
Segregation of the military
While the violent racism associated with the South mostly started during Reconstruction after the war, there was still racism both before and during the war. It also didn't help that a contributing factor in Secession was fear that slaves, if given a simultaneous blanket emancipation and allowed to arm themselves, would attack their former masters (a la the 1804 Haiti Genocide.)*** Thus, while the Confederacy did end up attempting to form "colored" units at the close of the war, this was very much a measure of last resort.
As for your scenario: while I don't think it's entirely infeasible that the Confederacy would have eventually formed a few black units as the free population gradually grew, I also don't think that they would have mixed units. Even the North didn't desegregate units until 1948.
Amphibious Assault Ship
Sure; I imagine they could probably get one or two surplus from other countries. While I don't know about France, Russia is a possibility (either as political maneuvering by the USSR or as a result of the bargain-basement prices of Soviet gear after the USSR went kaput.)
Service rifle
If, as you say, your Confederacy continues to have the same level (or lack thereof) of manufacturing capability relative to the Union, my money's on the Kalashnikov system. It's (fairly) reliable, uses lots of interchangeable parts between variants, and is cheap and simple to procure as surplus or make yourself.
The FN FAL is also an option. The G3 could be somewhat difficult for the CSA, as a decidedly non-NATO-member, to procure.
That said, as AlexP pointed out, your assumption of a manufacturing-poor Confederacy might be hard to explain. The Confederacy's lands are/were very difficult to defend (although you partially address that with the Texas war). Similarly to Nazi Germany in WWII, the CSA was doomed from the moment it failed to decapitate the Union at the beginning of the war (and probably would have still been doomed had that succeeded). Amateur strategists study tactics; professionals study logistics.
If your Confederacy is to have any chance of making it to the present day, it must have manufacturing capabilities at least rivaling those of the Union in terms of both quantity and quality (the latter because, unlike the Soviet Union, it cannot depend on throwing men at the problem to compensate.)

(N.B.: I wrote this answer while sleep-deprived. I'll come back and edit it up to my normal standards later.)
* Note that this is a bit oversimplified to make my point. As with anything to do with Secession and the Civil War, it's very complex.
** As with my previous footnote: this is an extremely complex and contentious topic due to elapsed time, a lot of contributing factors, and 160 years of propaganda by both sides. Most of it isn't very relevant to the topic at hand, so I have condensed it down to the relevant bit.
*** At risk of sounding like a broken record, this was very complex. The TL;DR is that, as with the current dispute over US border policy, the views of a small but vocal minority defined how each side viewed the other, with most people falling somewhere closer to the middle. The North's vocal minority was those who advocated for complete, total, and instant abolition, "and damn the consequences!"

Note that I am not pro-slavery, an unreconstructed Confederate, or anything like that. I'm just noting that this is how many Southerners viewed the North.


The first elephant in the room: Nuclear Weapons
Do they have nukes, or don't they? If they do not have nukes, and they US does, what is their strategic concept? If they do have nukes, those are their main strategic deterrent, and keeping and managing them will be the key consideration of their forces. Even more than North Korea in the real world. You have the stratgic rocket forces (TELs with IRBMs? Or SSBNs for a survivable deterrence?) and they hog most of the budget. Yet nuking an entire rebellious countryside is no viable strategy, those plantations belong to someone who wants to get them back.
This could be resolved by having no Manhattan project and no nukes in your world. Perhaps because there was no WWII?
The second elephant in the room: Alliances
For a long time, the United States believed that they should keep out of European and global quarrels and the alliances which formed. The US somewhat 'backslid' during WWI, arguably because a more industrialized world did not leave the Atlantic broad enough it case Germany won. Same during WWII. And after the second World War, they had learned their lesson and became the 'leader of the free world.' Because it was better to stand with anti-communists in Europe than to stand alone against an Eurasia occupied by communists.
A post-secession United States would be compelled to seek alliances if the Confederates do. Does the Civil-War-Era influence of cotton exporters start an alliance between the CSA and the British? With what allies does that leave the USA?
You did mention China. But who stopped Japan from conquering China? Chinese guerillas, or industrialized powers fighting Japan for their own reasons?
Your USA would need an army designed for a continental war in North America. More Army, less Navy. A much more tactical Air Force. How does your CSA counter that? Plenty of SAMs and cannon AAA?
So, consider elements of these:

The North Korean forces.
In the last century, they had chemical artillery menacing Seoul near the border. In this century, they developed nuclear weapons and put them on missiles. So how did the de-facto borders end after the Civil War? Any big cities within range of big, 1910s-style artillery? Something with the look-and-feel of the 155mm GPF, augmented a few years later by railway artillery or rail-mobile emplacement artillery. 21st century precision weapons made them less survivable, but there are lots of them close to the border. Their ammunition is older than the conscripts who serve them, their prime movers have no fuel (sold on the black market?), yet if the order comes they can fire a disastrous barrage against the border region.

The Soviet forces.
To go with the legacy focus on artillery, there are lots of mass-produced medium tanks. One on one, they are less lethan than the US standard models, but there are still lots of them. The CSA never throws them away, they get handed down from first-line forces to second-line-forces to third-line reserves to their style of national guard. Consider many units with a few cadre troops and lots and lots of assigned reservists. They would range from "almost as good as regulars" to "a complete waste of money and fuel."
You mentioned COIN. They might do it like the Soviets did in Afghanistan, or Chechnya.

Apartheid-era South African forces.
Your CSA will actually have two fronts, the northern one against the USA and the southern one against banana republics, either failed states or US allies. Against those, it might have technological superiority, but it will need to husband resources. Lots and lots of MRAPs?


.

Concerning nuclear weapons, the CSA actually has a handful of them (much to the ire of the United States for very obvious reasons). The Confederate nuclear arsenal numbers at around 30-60 nuclear weapons, most of which were procured in the mid-80s' to early 90s' with the help of defecting Soviet scientists. Interestingly, the CSA also has a rather shockingly advanced bioweapons program with covert help from China (this is how the CSA was able to create the Black Flu virus in my world).

Alliances; for context, the U.S. was the 2nd global superpower just behind China, at least prior to The Collapse (Black Flu virus kills billions and initiates a zombie outbreak around the world, which left the U.S. as the sole de facto global superpower after China collapsed into anarchy and civil war). Prior to The Collapse, the U.S. was part of 3 major transnational military alliances: NATO, SEATO, and the Pan-American Collective Defense/PACDEF (PACDEF is a joint U.S.-Canadian-Mexican-Gran Colombian alliance meant to fight and contain the CSA).

@user69268 an abysmal and appalling state. It’s poorly trained and equipped, morale is low, corruption is rife throughout the ranks and yet it has the technological, economic, and political infrastructure to have 30-60 nukes? And an advanced bioweapon program? That makes no believable sense at all.

As for the Confederacy's allies, they are few. The CSA is first and foremost an isolationist pariah state and maintains regular diplomatic relations with only a handful of countries. Their oldest and closest ally would be the Brazilian Federation, an authoritarian military dictatorship. Their most recent and beneficial partners would be China and Russia, both of whom provide the country with economic support and limited secret military assistance in exchange for keeping the U.S. occupied in North America, resource extraction rights, and hosting intel units in-country.

@JBH do keep in mind that this is a WIP and I'm still adjusting things. But if I had to try and justify it, the CSA is only able to remain alive in this capacity on account of foreign support, mainly stemming from China and Russia.

The creation of nuclear weapons in WWII took the financial resources of the US. It was almost impossible for the US to do it. The CSA won't have the resources to do that - emotional, political, and economic. The CSA is built upon an agricultural society, not an industrial society and won't support building the industrial base. Such industrialization is counter to the highly conservative nature of the CSA.

@JBH, how would you characterize the DPRK armed forces, as a whole? There are elites, and there are troops used to farm and log wood.

@DavidR, doing the Manhattan Project for the first time, in a few years, was really hard. Doing it the second time, in a decade, was much easier. Compare the US, Soviet, French, South African, and North Korean projects.

@o.m. The DPRK does not meet the OP's description, which is dire. If the OP were to choose to model his/her CSA military and government on North Korea, that would work just dandy, would be far more realistic than the route she/he is taking, and would be much faster.

@JBH, I did interpret it as pretty DPRK-like. The "arduous march," Songbun, the military fed at the expense of the people, and even that not being enough to fill their bellies.

@o.m. Certainly the first time was really hard. The premise of this question is that the US lost the Civil War. That puts in doubt the ability of the US to do the first time. It is entirely possible that we would be in a world without any nuclear weapons.

There definitely needs to be some more explanation for this, as it doesn't seem like this would work. As others have mentioned, if the military is in such a poor state, how do they still exist? But also, why would anyone fight for this kind of military? Or in general, if the military is any indication of the rest of the country. This kind of nation is unsustainable due to its lack of defenses, and lack of methods to keep its people. If you were a citizen who had just been drafted into this army(because who would volunteer for this), why go and probably bleed out while your CO gets their allergies treated when you could instead bribe a guard and leave, or just sneak out? Especially since it seems the Union would encourage this heavily. There needs to be some more reasons as to why the CSA even still exists if this is the state it's in. One way is maybe political reasons, say maybe it's backed by a foreign power. Or the USA military is in a similarly poor state, whether for the same reasons or different. But either way, some more details are needed as to why the CSA still exists.

There definitely needs to be some more explanation for this...  which is an admission that you shouldn't have answered the question but should have instead voted to close it.

People will fight for their "tribe" which is how much of the CSA army was organized.
